# How to catch an error and return it, on hosted hosted web api .net ... here is my code below

Tags: c#

How to catch an error and return it, on hosted hosted web api .net ... here is my code below....

```
public static ClientContext GetClientContext(string siteURL, string userName, string password, int foldernam)
{

            List<int> folderNames = new List<int>();
            folderNames.Add(foldernam);


                using (var context = new ClientContext(siteURL))
                {
                try
                {
                    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, ToSecureString(password));
                    Web web = context.Web;
                    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Bids");
                    var folder = list.RootFolder;
                    context.Load(folder);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (int folderName in folderNames)
                    {
                        ListItemCreationInformation newItemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                        newItemInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
                        newItemInfo.LeafName = folderName.ToString();
                        ListItem newListItem = list.AddItem(newItemInfo);
                        newListItem["Title"] = folderName;
                        newListItem.Update();
                    }
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    return context;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // i need to return an error here??????how do i return
                    //return ClientContext 
                    //throw ex;
                }

            }

}
```

Comment: Normally your method would return type would be a Task<IHttpActionResult>  and in your exception handler return InternalServerError() (500)

Answer (score 1):

with webapi2 you can throw a HttpResponseException:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling).
I hope this helps?

EDIT: custom error information:
from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling):

For more control over the response, you can also construct the entire response message and include it with the HttpResponseException:

```
public Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No product with ID = {0}", id)),
            ReasonPhrase = "Product ID Not Found"
        };
        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Throw exception doesn't show error details, i want to return the error so that i can see the error message...be mindful i am making a call on server that is published and hosted independently...

Comment: I updated my answer, this will return an error message. now it's up to the client to handle the exception.